# Sending large JSON files via sockets

Tags: java, json, sockets

Well this is embarassing. I am trying to send a large JSON file via sockets, and naturally the string exceeded the limit, so I tried compressing it, but for some strange reason I only get a single byte on the server-side. This is what I have so far:

Server-side:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String str;
while((str = request.getReader().readLine()) != null)
    sb.append(str);
Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 8081);

OutputStream outServer = client.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(outServer));
byte[] buff = sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println(buff.length);
out.writeInt(buff.length);
out.write(buff);
out.flush(); 
client.close();
```

The length of *buf* is 198153 in the particular case that I am trying to make this work.

The client-side:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8081);
Socket server = serverSocket.accept();

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(server.getInputStream()));
System.out.println(in.available());
int len = in.readInt();
byte[] buff = new byte[len];
in.readFully(buff);
String response = new String(buff, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(response);

updateMessage(response);
server.close();
serverSocket.close();
```

the *in.available()* is just 1 in this case, and the program doesn't execute anymore, it just stops there (it doesn't terminate though)
Any ideas? I thought that it might be helpful to get an outside perspective, because it might be something that I am missing out, something obvious. Thanks.

Comment: A side note: `InflaterInputStream.available()` will return 1 before EOF and 0 after EOF. In this case it simply means the stream has data.

Comment: "*naturally the string exceeded the limit*" - what limit are you referring to? And why is the *client* creating a *server socket*, and the *server* is creating a *client socket*? In any case, when dealing with socket input, you should usually include input buffering, eg: `DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(server.getInputStream())));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I only had to remove the GZIPInputStream and GZIPOutputStream, so feel free to use this technique whenever you want to send large Strings with Sockets, I couldn't find any other/better way on the Internet either.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending just one message per connection (which would be inefficient for small messages but for larger enough ones it doesn't matter so much) I would just send the entire message as text and read the whole message in one go.

NOTE: your code drops all newlines which I suspect wasn't intended.

For writing one message per connection.

```
try (Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 8081);
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()), "UTF-8")) {
    char[] chars = new char[8192];
    for (int len; (len = request.read(chars)) > 0;)
         writer.write(chars, 0, len);
}
```

for reading

```
try (Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
     Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(server.getInputStream()), "UTF-8")) {
     // read the text as above.
}
```

Comment: that's how I did it in the beginning..but I got an exception that the String was too big for the DataOutputStream. The new lines are dropped if I chop the String into bytes? Nope not intended and not wanted either.

Comment: @BetimNeutron newlines are dropped if you do `readLine()` which consumes the new line and `append` which only writes the contents of the line.